# I have written my own http server and I want to execute a cgi script through this server. But i don't know how to do that

Tags: c, http, cgi

How does apache execute a binary or executable file? I want to write same application for my http server.

Comment: You need to implement the [Common Gateway Interface](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875). If you have any particular difficulties doing this, then please ask specific questions here. As it stands, your question is far too broad to be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it executes the CGI program in the usual Unix way: it creates some pipes so that it can feed data to the CGI and retrieve the response, then it `fork`s a child and in the child, it:

- reopens stdin, stdout and stderr to the appropriate pipes
- loads up the environment with the CGI environment variables (and cleans out other environment variables which shouldn't leak into the CGI program),
- and finally `execv`s the CGI program.

That's the easy part. The tricky part is feeding the HTTP request body through the pipe and retrieving the response, without either blocking or reading too far into the socket. (And handling any transport encoding, chunking, compression, etc., so that the CGI just sees a request.)